# Android: Memory friendly modification of image bytes

Tags: java, android, bitmap, bitmapfactory

I'm currently making an Android App that modifies some bytes of an image. For this, I've written this code:

```
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(path));
ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(bmp.getWidth()*bmp.getHeight());
bmp.copyPixelsToBuffer(buffer);
return buffer.array();
```

The problem is that this way uses too much Heap memory, and throws `OutOfMemoryException`. 
I know that I can make the heap memory for the App bigger, but it doesn't seem like a good design choice.

Is there a more memory-friendly way of changing bytes of an image?

Comment: Increasing the heap may not actually be a bad design choice in this situation. Image editors in particular require more heap memory than a regular app. In fact, this is the one example case where using a larger heap size is recomeneded (check out the Google I/O lecture on memory managment - I think its from 2011).

Comment: `buffer` is a `ByteBuffer`?

Comment: @fge Yes, I'll add it to the post.

Comment: @Rarw I'll watch the Google I/O lecture. Thanks for the hint!

Comment: Maybe you could use a memory mapped file instead of a buffer allocated on the heap?

Comment: Accessing it as a memory-mapped file would require decoding the input (which is likely a compressed format) and writing it back out, then reversing the process to save the image.  Ideally the image would be kept in memory, but if the image is large enough this might be the only option.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there are two copies of the pixel data on the managed heap:

- The uncompressed data in the `Bitmap`
- The copy of the data in the `ByteBuffer`

The memory requirement could be halved by leaving the data in the Bitmap and using `getPixel()` / `setPixel()` (or perhaps editing a row at a time with the "bulk" variants), but that adds some overhead.

Depending on the nature of the image, you may be able to use a less precise format (e.g. RGB 565 instead of 8888), halving the memory requirement.

As noted in one of the comments, you could uncompress the data to a file, memory-map it with `java.nio.channels.FileChannel#map()`, and access it through a `MappedByteBuffer`.  This adds a fair bit of overhead to loading and saving, and may be annoying since you have to work through a `ByteBuffer` rather than a `byte[]`.

Another option is expanding the heap with `android:largeHeap` ([documented here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html)), though in some respects you're just postponing the inevitable: you may be asked to edit an image that is too large for the "large" heap.  Also, the capacity of a "large" heap varies from device to device, just as the "normal-sized" heap does.  Whether or not this makes sense depends in part on how large the images you're loading are.

Before you do any of this I'd recommend using the heap analysis tools (see e.g. [this blog post](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/03/memory-analysis-for-android.html)) to see where your memory is going.  Also, look at the logcat above the out-of-memory exception; it should identify the size of the allocation that failed.  Make sure it looks "reasonable", i.e. you're not inadvertently allocating significantly more than you think you are.